# How to change by default blue round location icon in google map fragment in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

The blue round icon of current location that appears on map fragment when we enable `setMylocationEnabled(true)` is required to be changed in my scenario. How can I achieve that by default a vehicle icon appear instead of blue icon. Thank you.

Comment: There is also an open feature request for customizing the blue current location icon in Google Public Issue Tracker. You may check it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/169729868

Comment: I finally changed via setMyLocationEnabled(false) and then onLocationChange setting the position of my custom icon. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,works for me

```
  ImageView btnMyLocation = (ImageView) ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
    btnMyLocation.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_current_location);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
            btnMyLocation.getLayoutParams();

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
    btnMyLocation.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: It is changing the button's icon. However I need to change the default icon of location pointer basically, which is blue. Thankyou

Comment: just changing to the vehicle icon is fine

Comment: I want to change the blue marker that shows our position on the map. It is round and blue in color. I just want to replace that blue icon with my own drawable. Thankyou